# I want a backpack on my back and waist

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode, makehuman

My model data. The back belt is oddly detached from the body.

[image]

How do I fix this?

I uploaded my data. It doesn't use auto weight yet. I want to relate collect with born.

The first picture one is just used auto weight. It was related to backpack and bone.

I added bone is it need to connect these bone?
How to connect?
I tried to parent.
But those can connect lonely bone head to back.
It seems good to connect back and back.
[image]

And I tried connecting the top of the backpack bones.
It can't make parents.
It can't select ctrl P many.
It becomes gray.

I uploaded blender file again.
[image]

Comment: I added bone is it needed to connect these bones? How to connect? I tried to parent. But those can connect lonely bone head to back. It seems good to connect back and back. enter the image description here

And I tried connecting the top of the backpack bones. It can't make parents. It can't select ctrl P many. It becomes gray.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for the moment your bag object is not controlled by any bone. You need to create a series of bones that will control your bag and its straps, then parent these bones to one of the existing spine bones:

[image]