# I want to link the back pack with spine

Tags: armature, bones, makehuman

My model data. The back belt is oddly detached from the body.
I added bone is it needed to connect these bones? How to connect? I tried to parent. But those can connect the lonely bone head to the back. It seems good to link back and back.
[image]

And I tried to connect the top of the backpack bones. It can't make parents. It cants select ctrl P many. It becomes gray.

My model data. The back belt is oddly detached from the body.[image]

How do I fix this?

[image]

I uploaded again but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: You already have an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274890/i-want-a-backpack-on-my-back-and-waist?rq=1

Comment: I got the answer I tried to watch it.
But I couldn't.
I am asking the next things.
That's diffelent.

Comment: Ok. You added the bones for the backpack as a new armature (Armature.001) rather than adding them to the existing armature. You're trying to parent bones from different armatures. That's why the parenting menu is greyed out.

Comment: I tried to do that.
But the back belt is still oddly detached from the body.
I uploaded new data.